# Row number only for matching rows by id?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have table structure like

```
Category EmpName
   1      Harry
   1      John
   1      Ford 
   2      James
   2      Mark  
   2      Shane 
   3      Oliver 
   3       Ted
```

I want results like

```
Category EmpName RowNumber
   1      Harry      1
   1      John       2 
   1      Ford       3
   2      James      1
   2      Mark       2
   2      Shane      3
   3      Oliver     1
   3      Ted        2
```

I am using db2 and row_number() is not working for different groups of records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used DB2, but based on my googling, it looks like the row_number() function does support the partition by clause.

Try this:

```
select category, empname, row_number() over(partition by category)
```